# MPDF: Latin characters appear in bold in Japanese texts

Tags: php, mpdf

I use MPDF 8 to generate PDFs in Japanese. The problem is that Latin characters appear in bold.

This is a screenshot of what I get:

[image]

This is how I configure MPDF:

```
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf([
  'mode' => 's', 
  'format' => 'A4', 
  'default_font_size' => '12', 
  'default_font' => 'SJIS',
]);

$mpdf->autoScriptToLang = true;
$mpdf->autoLangToFont = true;
```

I tried many other configurations, but nothing works. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your example renders _correctly_ (non-bold, serif font) in windows and linux with the [example HTML you have shared](https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf/issues/1834) in the github issue. There has to be something in your environment you are not sharing. Widen your example code and specifics of your setup.

Comment: The actual generated PDF would also help.